# formatting problems with VSCode and svelte

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte

I'm running into some strange formatting issues with vscode using svelte. Whenever I create an HTML tag, say `<p></p>`, as soon as I save or click elsewhere, it reformats to this: `<p />`. I have no idea what's going on. It also doesn't seem to like certain Svelte tags like `<slot></slot>`. Has anyone else encountered this? If so, what did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the official Svelte extension, it only comes with one way of formatting the code: Prettier.

If you want control back, turn off `svelte.plugin.svelte.format.enable`. You could also create a [`.prettierrc`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html) and see if there are any Prettier options to change this particular behavior.

---

By the way: Even though something like `<div />` would be invalid in HTML, it is not in Svelte because the code gets compiled anyway.

If you have just a `div` like that in a component, it gets compiled to:

```js
function create_fragment(ctx) {
    let div;

    return {
        c() {
            div = element("div");
        },
        m(target, anchor) {
            insert(target, div, anchor);
        },
        p: noop,
        i: noop,
        o: noop,
        d(detaching) {
            if (detaching) detach(div);
        }
    };
}
```

Or with SSR:

```js
const App = create_ssr_component(($$result, $$props, $$bindings, slots) => {
    return `<div></div>`;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Svelte for VS Code extension, you can enable svelte strict mode in extension settings, or put this in settings.json
"svelte.plugin.svelte.format.config.svelteStrictMode": true